# Regex question with spaces ruining the targeted words

Tags: regex

I'm having issues with writing out an expression to block some words.

This is my current code.
I am currently just using regex101.com to test it.

```
(^[GgƓɠḠḡǴǵĜĝǦǧĞğĢģǤǥĠġ](?:[^a-zA-Z]*)([ÂâÅåÀàÁáÃãÄäEeAaÆæ4@]+\s{0,30})([.*\S*]{0,1}$)|(?:[^a-zA-Z]*)[ÝýŶŷŸÿỸỹYy].)
```

I'm needing this to find the word "gay" but if someone writes "gay man" with a space, it doesn't even pickup the word "gay". I'm just trying to figure out why the space allows the word, I tried moving things around and adding what I could that might make sense but nothing seems to click here.

Comment: You can exclude it using a negative lookahead `^[GgƓɠḠḡǴǵĜĝǦǧĞğĢģǤǥĠġ][ÂâÅåÀàÁáÃãÄäEeAaÆæ4@][ÝýŶŷŸÿỸỹYy](?! man\b)` https://regex101.com/r/UyIwll/1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I want to share this post to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4867612

I'm not sure I understood correctly, but with only this `[GgƓɠḠḡǴǵĜĝǦǧĞğĢģǤǥĠġ][ÂâÅåÀàÁáÃãÄäEeAaÆæ4@][ÝýŶŷŸÿỸỹYy]`
in https://regex101.com/r/jYpHJS/1 you can detect if the word gay is in text